# Abstraction and Navigation Drawer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I would like to pull a 'drawer' out of my scaffold so it's not repeated.

I have multiple screens, and the drawer is in every scaffold and it doesn't do much apart from serving as the navigation. Naturally, I'd like to pull it out of the scaffold and put it into a new dart file and call it on the pages (within the scaffold).

```
drawer: Drawer(
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.cyan[100],
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan[200]),
                child: Text('Profile Goes Here'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Main'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/landing');
                  }),
              ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Resume'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/resume');
                  }),
              ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Projects'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/projects');
                  }),
            ], // children of ListView
          ), // End of ListView
        ),
      ),
```

How could this be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- my_drawer.dart

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDrawer ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child:  Material(
        color: Colors.cyan[100],
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.cyan[200]),
              child: Text('Profile Goes Here'),
            ),
            ListTile(
                title: const Text('Main'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/landing');
                }),
             //.......you can put others widget here

         ], // children of ListView
        ), // End of ListView
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and now , `MyDrawer` is your component widget for drawer. you are free to use it in every `Scaffold` you have. no need to define every detail navigation, just set `MyDrawer` for drawer properties on scaffold.

eg:

landing.dart

```
import 'my_drawer.dart';

class landing extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF007B76),
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const MyDrawer(),  // just this , no need other
      body: Container()
    );
  }
}
```

repeat for another screen

- resume.dart

```
import 'my_drawer.dart';

// better use Capital letters for every class name
class Resume extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF007B76),
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const MyDrawer(), // simple like this, 
      body: Text("this is Resume"),
    );
  }
}
```

component widget in flutter is reusable, you may call it if it match the type. just plug and play.

Comment: So close!!! I was able to write "my_drawer.dart" and it looks good - thank you for the direction!

The only hurdle left is an error when connecting to "landing.dart" and I get the following error on my landing.dart file: 

"The argument type 'NavDrwr' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'"

I really appreciate the help pmatatias!!

Comment: can you provide snippet code from  `landing.dart`  and `my_drawer,dart` ,  im sure the `drawer` properties on `Scaffold` type is `Widget?`

Comment: yes! Glad to and sorry I couldn't figure out how to format in comments - here are all the files in .txt format (afraid to put .dart on the server)
https://outrightsites.com/sidedoor/temp/main.txt  //  https://outrightsites.com/sidedoor/temp/landing.txt  //  https://outrightsites.com/sidedoor/temp/resume.txt  //
https://outrightsites.com/sidedoor/temp/projects.txt  //  https://outrightsites.com/sidedoor/temp/nav.txt

Comment: @Graham you gotta miss what `StatefullWidget` or `StatelessWidget` in flutter. maybe you need to read basic information .
your `Navbar is not extend to any stateful, or stateless widget, it just a normal `class`.  thats why you can set `NavBr` to drawer , since it need widget  class

Comment: i just update my answer, you can follow it on your code. 
hope you can understand wht i mean.

Comment: Ah! Perfect @pmatatias - thank you soooo much! I compared your comments and noticed that I didn't have "Widget" in front of "build" and so I inserted. Error free. After rebooting my system, I can verify that it is working properly.

Thank you so much!!